# Do we need in-app billing for bitcoin-like app?

Tags: android, mobile

Apps that use bitcoin contains transactions e.g. deal with a real money. Google says that if we deal with a real money, it has to go over their in-app billing service.

I checked other bitcoin apps on the Google Play, but neither of them seem to have in-app billing implemented.

So do I have to implement in-app billing for bitcoin-like app or I can make transaction without it?

I don't want to build and publish the app which will be blocked as violating TOS.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Are you trying to charge the user, then send that money along? Are you trying to make a Bitcoin-like app where you pay to unlock features? etc.

Comment: Well basically are we allowed to sell&buy bitcoins without using Google inapp billing?

Comment: Are you just talking about letting people receive, store and send bitcoins, or actually letting them exchange bitcoins for dollars, euros, etc (or vice versa)? For the former, there are plenty of apps that do this without in-app billing (I don't see how you could even use in-app billing for such an app). For the latter, you probably would not only need to use Google's payment service but would also probably need their explicit permission.